# Two smooth atlases are smoothly equivalent IFF their corresponding spaces of smooth functions coincide

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to do below exercise from [this](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Ecrain101/manifolds-2018/chapter-manifolds.pdf) lecture note, i.e.,

> **Ex 3.1.** Given any two smooth atlases $\mathcal A_1, \mathcal A_2$ on a topological space $M$, we have $\mathcal A_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A_2$ if and only if $\mathcal C^\infty(M, \mathcal A_1) = \mathcal C^\infty(M, \mathcal A_2)$.

I have found a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717244/two-atlases-on-a-manifold-m-are-equivalent-if-and-only-if-they-determine-the-s) that uses an extension theorem. My proof does not use this theorem and is thus simpler.

> Could you check if I made some subtle mistake?

---

**My attempt** The direction "$\implies$" is straightforward. Let's prove the reverse. Let $\mathcal C^\infty(M, \mathcal A_1) = \mathcal C^\infty(M, \mathcal A_2)$. We will show that $\mathcal A_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A_2$. Fix charts $f:U \to \mathbb R^m$ in $\mathcal A_1$ and $g:V \to \mathbb R^m$ in $\mathcal A_2$. Let $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_m)$ and $N := U \cap V$. Then $N$ is open in $M$. It suffices to prove that
$$
f_1 \circ g^{-1} : g(N) \to f(N)
$$
is smooth in the usual sense.

Let $\mathcal A_1' := \{h |_{N} : h \in \mathcal A_1\}$ and $\mathcal A_2' := \{h |_{N} : h \in \mathcal A_2\}$. Then $\mathcal A_1', \mathcal A_2'$ are two smooth atlases on the topological space $N$ (endowed with subspace topology). It follows from $\mathcal A_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A_2$ that $\mathcal A'_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A'_2$. By direction "$\implies$", we get $\mathcal C^\infty(N, \mathcal A'_1) = \mathcal C^\infty(N, \mathcal A'_2)$.

Clearly, $f_1 |_N \in \mathcal C^\infty(N, \mathcal A'_1)$. So $f_1 |_N \in \mathcal C^\infty(N, \mathcal A'_2)$. On the other hand, $g|_N \in \mathcal A'_2$. It follows that $f_1 \circ g^{-1} |_{g(N)}$ is smooth. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It follows from $\mathcal A_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A_2$ that $\mathcal A'_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal A'_2$.

You use this line to conclude that $\mathcal{A}_1’$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal{A}_2’$. But you never proved that $\mathcal{A}_1$ is smoothly equivalent to $\mathcal{A}_2$. In fact, the equivalence of $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ is the very thing you’re trying to prove. Your reasoning is circular.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is there any way that avoids the use of such extension theorem?

Comment: @Analyst I can’t think of one immediately.